# Use Function Keys as Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, keyboard

I have a Macbook Pro 13" with Retina Display running OS X Mavericks 10.9.4

I use Code Editors like PHPStorm which Require me to use the Function Keys as Keyboard Shortcuts like Command+F6.

But F6 just increases my backlighting.

I want the function Keys to do this special stuff when used alone and behave as normal Function keys when I add something before it like Cmd.

For example :
F11 should decrease volume,
but Cmd+F11 should be a shortcut

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you got two options:

1. Enable function keys to work like normal keys and to activate their special functions – like increasing volume etc. – when pressing *fn* beforehand.

   - Open *System Preferences*
   - Select preference pane *Keyboard*
   - Select *Keyboard* tab
   - Activate option *Use all F1, F2, etc, keys as standard function keys*
     [image: Image courtesy by OSXDaily.com]

     > Image taken from [OSXDaily.com](http://osxdaily.com/2010/05/12/switch-your-mac-function-keys-to-work-as-standard-function-keys)
2. Set custom app shortcuts for your programs that need function keys in their shortcuts.

   - Open *System Preferences*
   - Select preference pane *Keyboard*
   - Select *Shortcuts* tab
   - Select group *App Shortcuts*
   - Press *+* and add your needed shortcuts – those already existent in the editor. Just select the corresponding app, insert the shortcut name (name in the menu connected to the shortcut) and enter shortcut already set by the program.
     [image: Image courtesy by geeksays.com]

     > Image taken from [Geeksays.com](http://www.geeksays.com/create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-os-x-mavericks/2029)